# Duda de condición if y timer en python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un codigo de control de extractores en base a temperatura y humedad.. en un principio son nueve condiciones.

En el caso de que ocurran dos de estas, se deberian apagar los dos extractores (F0). La regla es que no pueden estar apagados por mas de 30 minutos, y en ese caso se debe generar un periodo minimo de 30 minutos encendidos ambos (F1).
Aun no conecto los sensores(T y H) y actuadores(Extractores), estoy realizando el control con Raw_input desde consola para ir probando.

El problema que tengo es la condición de que si estan apagados por mas de 30 minutos, se prendan ambos por 30 minutos.
Hice el siguiente codigo, pero no está bien, al ocurrir esta condición se genera un bucle infinito con el timer que creé. quizas deba ser otro tipo de timer.

Codigo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from timeit import default_timer

T  = 0
Ti = 20
Ts = 25
H  = 0
Hs = 80
Hi = 50
Aux_timer = 0
tiempo = 0

while True:
    try:
        T=float(raw_input('Ingrese T:'))
        H=float(raw_input('Ingrese H:'))
    except ValueError:
        print "Ingrese un numero valido"


    if((Ti <T< Ts) and (Hi <H< Hs)) :
        print "F1"
    elif((Ti <T< Ts) and (H < Hi)) :
        print "F0"  
        start = default_timer()
        while True:          
            tiempo = default_timer() - start
            if (tiempo>30):             
                print "Se prenden ambos extractores"



    elif((Ti <T< Ts) and (H > Hs)) :
        print "F2"

    elif((T<Ti) and (Hi <H< Hs)) :
        print "F1"
    elif((T<Ti) and (H < Hi)) :
        print "F0"

    elif((T<Ti) and (H > Hs)) :
        print "F2"

    elif((T>Ts) and (Hi <H< Hs)):
         print "F2"
    elif((T>Ts) and (H < Hi)) :
         print "F2"
    elif((T>Ts) and (H > Hs)) :
         print "F2"
    else:
        print "Error"
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece que está en el segundo `while`, una vez que entra ahí ya no vuelve a salir. Quizá un `if` sería más adecuado ahí. También puedes salir de un bucle `while` usando `break`. No te pongo código ya que no me queda claro lo que quieres hacer.

Otra cosa, si no quieres estar ejecutando el código de forma continua y quieres que ciertas comprobaciones se hagan cada cierto tiempo y así no consumir CPU puedes usar `time.sleep` indicando el espacio de tiempo que quieres que el programa esté parado entre comprobaciones de las condiciones.

Comment: Gracias, encontré algo que seria mas adecuado, que es `t = threading.Timer(tiempo, funcion)` . lo que necesito es que al cumplirse la condicion de que los dos extractores esten apagados, si al pasar 30 minutos siguen apagados, que se prendan arbitrariamente 30 minutos denuevo, por sobre las 9 condiciones en base a Temperatura y humedad.

Comment: Creo que es más sencillo que usando *threading* a no ser que quieras desbloquear tu programa para que siga haciendo otras cosas, asíncrono vs síncrono.

Comment: Creo que confundes asincronía con concurrencia: Aquí te dejo un divertido artículo sobre concurrencia en Python: https://blog.aitorciki.net/2012/04/27/concurrencia-en-python/

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, no hay que confundin un proceso asincrono, esto es que se ejecuta no en sincronia con mi applicación y lo que es multithreading (que tiene sus peros en python --> ojo con GIL) y multiprocess.